# Laravel/php | Как из Route получить параметр адресной строки (?par=123)

Tags: php, laravel, url

Адресная строка: http://127.0.0.1:8000/atom/?search=123
Необходимо получить значение параметра search либо сам параметр с помощью Route, код ниже не работает.

```
Route::get('/atom/{search}', function ($search) {
   return 'search:'.$search;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::get('/atom', function (\Illuminate\Http\Request $request) {
    $search = $request->search;
    return 'search:'.$search;
});
```